# Difference between {} and [] in React js for default states

Tags: reactjs

what is the difference between `{}` and `[]` in using states for React.js?

Such as `[name,setName]=useState({})` compared to `[name,setName]=useState([])`

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want your default `name` to be? You can also use `useState(null)` or `useState('')`.

Comment: The difference is what matters it in core JavaScript between object and array.

Comment: `[]` means its an array while `{}` is an object. Putting in the `useState` just defines ur default state to be whatever of the two types.

Answer (score 2):

That sets the default value of name. It's either an empty object {} or an empty array [].

Answer (score 2):

We will be setting the initial state. In your case {} (empty object) and [] (empty array).

**Few examples which I have used:**

```
const [paymentMethod, setPaymentMethod] = useState('PayPal')
const [countInStock, setCountInStock] = useState(0)
const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false)
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null)
```

URL: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

[image]